# JSON file with input from filename using bash

Tags: python, json, bash, terminal

I am very new to bash scripting.

I have set of JSON files as follows:

```
sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_idir-acq-LR_epi.json
sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_idir-acq-RL_epi.json
sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-RL_idir-acq-LR_epi.json
sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-RL_idir-acq-RL_epi.json
```

Now looking at the each .json filename, I want to have key value pair inside the .json file. For eg: for file `sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_idir-acq-LR_epi.json`
i want to include following information:

```
{
"PhaseEncodingDirection": "-i",
"TotalReadoutTime": 0.08346,
"IntendedFor": "func/sub-285345_task-rest_acq-LR_run-01_bold.nii.gz"
}
```

`PhaseENcodingDirection` is derived from `idir-acq-LR` in the filename. For `LR` its `-i` and for `RL` its `i`.

How can this be done using bash script preferably if not then in python.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "looking at each .json filename, I want to have key value pair inside the .json file". Do you want to add data to the JSON currently in the file? How are you getting the values for "TotalReadoutTime" and "IntendedFor"?

Comment: @bytesized "TotalReadoutTime" and "IntendedFor" values are same by default... If the .json filename as idir-acq value as LR i want this to be translated to "PhasEncodingDirection": "-i".. So the "-i" or +i will be dependent upon idir value in the file name. LR os -i and RL is +i

Comment: Take a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for parsing JSON in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try below node js script

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('.', function(err, files) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        var obj = {
            "TotalReadoutTime": 0.08346,

        };

        if (file.indexOf("idir-acq-LR") > -1) {
            console.log(file);
            obj.PhaseEncodingDirection = "-i";
            var intendedForPart1 =  file.replace(/'-EMOTION-acq-LR'/g,'-rest_acq-LR');
            var intendedForPart2 =  intendedForPart1.replace(/'_epi.json'/g,'_run-01_bold.nii.gz');
            obj.IntendedFor = 'func/' + intendedForPart2;
            fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf-8');
        } else if (file.indexOf("idir-acq-RL") > -1) {
            console.log(file);
            obj.PhaseEncodingDirection = "i";
            var intendedForPart1 =  file.replace(/'-EMOTION-acq-RL'/g,'-rest_acq-RL');
            var intendedForPart2 =  intendedForPart1.replace(/'_epi.json'/g,'_run-01_bold.nii.gz');
            obj.IntendedFor = 'func/' + intendedForPart2;
            //obj.IntendedFor = "func/sub-285345_task-rest_acq-RL_run-01_bold.nii.gz"
            fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf-8');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: The question requests either a `bash` or `python` solution, not `Node.js`.

Comment: @Sham332 It is editing all other files from the directory too. I want to edit only files ending with .json and having a pattern of sub-285345_task*.json.

Comment: @Sham332 I am ok with node js just that i have to do one more operation then. I want to edit the intended for as well as per the .json filename. If the filename is  `sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-RL_idir-acq-RL_epi.json` i want IntendedFor filed to be: `func/sub-285345_task-EMOTION_acq-RL_bold.nii.g`. Basically i want to have tast-EMOTION_acq-RL from the filename and in place of idir_acq-RL_epi.json i would like to have _bold.nii.gz.. can this be done in node js too..?

Comment: I have added replace logic as above. Hope this is helpful